# Function which returns multiple values

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

In Fortran, is it possible to define a function which returns multiple values like below?

```
[a, b] = myfunc(x, y)
```

Comment: It can return multiple values (see below), but you can't have multiple assignments in a single line like in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends... With `functions`, it is not possible to have two distinct function results. However, you can have an array of length two returned from the function.

```
  function myfunc(x, y)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: x,y
    integer             :: myfunc(2)

    myfunc = [ 2*x, 3*y ]
  end function
```

If you need two return values to two distinct variables, use a `subroutine` instead:

```
  subroutine myfunc(x, y, a, b)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: x,y
    integer, intent(out):: a,b

    a = 2*x
    b = 3*y
  end subroutine
```

Comment: Thanked you, Alexander. Your answer is exactly what I have been looking for!

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is, if you really want to have a single output variable, then you can combine all the outputs of the same data type in an array and return it, although this is not better than the method discussed above.