# Calling Fortran Subroutines from C code

Tags: c, fortran, cygwin, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I got one fortran code (gmf.f) working great and I want to call it from c (tropo.c) so I can use the outputs of fortran subroutine in my c code as new variables.

```
subroutine gmf (dmjd,dlat,dlon,dhgt,zd,gmfh,gmfw)

C     This subroutine determines the Global Mapping Functions GMF

C     input data
C     ----------
C     dmjd: modified julian date   (real)
C     dlat: ellipsoidal latitude in radians  (real)
C     dlon: longitude in radians      (real)
C     dhgt: height in m                  (real)
C     zd:   zenith distance in radians        (real)
C
C     output data
C     -----------
C     gmfh: hydrostatic mapping function      (real)
C     gmfw: wet mapping function              (real)
C
C     Johannes Boehm, 2005 August 30
C     Rev. Boehm 21 July 2011: latitude -> ellipsoidal latitude
C

      implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
```

...
...
...
...
After some maths and computation as a result, I'm getting the outputs gmfh and gmfw.

Since I'm not good at C I wrote one sample after some research on the WEB. What I'm struggling I don't know how to call the results from fortran into the c and see them on the screen... I'd be really appreciate if anyone help me to find the solution...

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {




 double gmf_(double *dmjd, double *dlat, double *dlon, double *dhgt, double *zd, double *gmfh, double *gmfw);

 double dmjd=53120;
  double dlat=38.25;
  double dlon=42.25;
  double dhgt=700.25;
  double zd=60.0;


 ??? double result???? = gmf_(&dmjd, &dlat, &dlon, &dhgt, &zd, &gmfh, &gmfw);

  return;
  }
```

finally ı will execute in cygwin

gfortran -c gmf.f

gcc -c tropo.c

gfortran -o solve gmf.o tropo.o

./solve

and will see the results on the screen: gmfh and gmfw.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with C++.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147425/c-returning-fortran-results tidied up a little ?

Comment: You should edit and improve your old question. Do not repost the same, you risk don-votes and even a ban. Please note, deleted questions do count towards the question ban.

Comment: But gmf_ definitely does not return a double. It does not return anything in Fortran and hence it does not return anything in C. You must first understand how the subroutine works and what the arguments (parameters) do and only after that you can use it in C. The documentation in the Fortran code clearly states which arguments are the output.

Comment: BTW publishing a code in 2005 and 2011 which starts with `implicit double precision` is almost an offence.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, please try the following modifications. The key point is that because `gmf()` is a Fortran `subroutine` (not a `function`), it returns nothing as the return variable. So we do not need to write `result = gmf_(...);` but rather simply write `gmf_(...);`. Please note that the values of `gmfh` and `gmfw`will be modified directly by `gmf()` on the Fortran side, because they are passed by pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Use "void" here because gmf() is a subroutine (with no return variable).
void gmf_ (double *dmjd, double *dlat, double *dlon,
           double *dhgt, double *zd,
           double *gmfh, double *gmfw);

int main()
{
    double dmjd = 1.0, dlat = 2.0, dlon = 3.0,
           dhgt = 4.0, zd   = 5.0;

    double gmfh, gmfw;

    // Call the Fortran routine. No need to write "result = gmf_(...)".
    // Instead, the values of gmfh and gmfw will be modified directly by gmf().
    gmf_ ( &dmjd, &dlat, &dlon, &dhgt, &zd, &gmfh, &gmfw );

    printf( "gmfh = %15.8f\n", gmfh );
    printf( "gmfw = %15.8f\n", gmfw );

    return 0;
}
```

If you use a simpler version of `gmf()`, e.g.,

```
      subroutine gmf ( dmjd, dlat, dlon, dhgt, zd, gmfh, gmfw )

C     input data  : dmjd, dlat, dlon, dhgt, zenith
C     output data : gmfh, gmfw

c     implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)    !! this is not recommended...
      implicit none
      double precision :: dmjd, dlat, dlon, dhgt, zd, gmfh, gmfw

      gmfh = dmjd + dlat + dlon + dhgt
      gmfw = zd * 10.0d0
      end
```

(here `gmf.f` is assumed to be fixed-format), we get

```
gmfh =     10.00000000
gmfw =     50.00000000
```

Some side notes:

- AFAIK there is no automatic mechanism for checking the correctness of argument type matching between C and Fortran. So please check the declaration of types in the prototype very carefully so that they precisely match those in Fortran routines. Not only the types of variables (e.g., `integer`, `real`, ...) but also their kinds (e.g., `real(xxx)` or `double precision` etc) are also critically important.
- If possible, please try using `implicit none` in Fortran routines because it makes much easier to detect any typos or type mismatch.
- Once the code runs, please also consider using `iso_c_binding` (particularly `bind(C)`) to make the interface more portable.

Comment: Thanks roygvib...Your answer works well...Later, I change my fortran structure to function with "function (dmjd, dlat, dlon, dhgt, zd)  result(gmfh, gmfw)" and it worked as well with my c code

Comment: Hmm, you may need some caution to get multiple return variables from Fortran `function`; please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120263/function-which-returns-multiple-values/  (though this QA is not about C-Fortran interface). If necessary, please consider posting a different quetion (because it is a very different topic, I guess).